# Safari Push Notifications - Signature File Generation in .Net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, safari, notifications, digital-signature

I'm trying to create the signature file for safari push notifications in .Net Core 3.1.  The Apple docs state that it should be a PKCS #7 detached signature of the manifest file using the created push certificate and AppleWWDRCA file.

I have managed to create a valid signature file using the php companion file that apple provide so I know the other files in my push package are valid.

However, whenever I try and create the signature in c# I get the error "Signature verification of push package failed" logged.

My current version of the code is below although I have tried various combinations of IncludeOptions and SignedAttributes.  My Apple certificate is loaded as a pem file.

I have tried looking at how this library does it for passbooks but it still fails. https://github.com/tomasmcguinness/dotnet-passbook

I would be grateful to anybody who can help!

```
private void GenerateSignatureFile()
{            
     ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(_manifestFile);

     var cms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);
     var signer = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, _request.Certificate);

     // I have tried changing this to a few other options.
     signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot;

     signer.Certificates.Add(_request.AppleIntermediaryCerificate);

     // I have tried adding this.
     //signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.Now));            

     cms.ComputeSignature(signer);

     _signatureFile = cms.Encode();                             
}
```